# Display messages/notifications in NetBox

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, netbox

I would like some help with messages in NetBox, please. I'm writing a custom validator and I need to display a warning message if for example a device name doesn't fit the company's policy. I can't use the standard fail method in the CustomValidator class - the edit request should be fulfilled, it's just supposed to warn the user as well. I would like to use a box message like [this one](https://github.com/netbox-community/netbox/discussions/9650), just with the warning level.

I tried something like this:

```py
from extras.validators import CustomValidator
from django.contrib import messages

class device_validator(CustomValidator):
    def validate(self, instance):
        if instance.name is not instance.name.upper():
            messages.info(request, "Names of devices should be in all-caps.")       
            return
```

But clearly, my syntax is wrong. I get the "Server Error" window and following message:

```py
<class 'NameError'>

name 'request' is not defined
```

How do I define the request? Could someone please give me an example how to display a message in this context?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

request probably needs to be self.request

```
messages.info(self.request, "Names of devices should be in all-caps.")
```